# Access database variable in functions with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am fairly new to PHP and I have found that a lot of my functions require access to the database. The problem is I currently connect to the database in a file that I require at the top of every page like so:

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
```

The problem I find is then when I want to access it within a function I have to pass the $db variable to it... which works fine, but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest (but not the best) way is to add 'global' keyword in each function. Example:

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
function foo() {
  global $db;
  $db->query(....
}
```

Much better way is to create your own class My_DB and define it as singleton. Then you will be able to call db object as an instance of the My_DB.

```
class My_DB {
  protected $_db = null;

  protected static $instance = null;

  protected function __construct() {
    $this->_db = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
  }

  public static function getInstance() {
    if (empty(self::$_instance)) {
      self::$_instance = new self();
    }
    return self::$_instance;
  }
}
```

And then anywhere in your code you can do the following:

```
function foo() {
  $db = My_DB::getInstance();
  $db->query(....
}
```

Comment: thanks it looks great... you say the second is 'much better' ... can I ask what the advantage is?

Comment: The second is better because global variable is accessible in any part of your code, so some third-party library (or your code) could redefine it. But you can't redefine class - this will cause fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

You can call them as functions on the `$db` object, e.g. `$db->query(...)`.

Comment: I understand this much... my problem is not getting $db to work.. it is that everytime I call a function I have to add $db as one of the variables that I pass to it... e.g FunctionName($var1,$var2,$db); is there not a better way to make $db accessable?

Comment: You want $db to be a global variable.  If you put an include file that defines $db outside the scope of any function, it will be available in any file that includes it.  If you want a more object-oriented method, have an include that creates a $db that's a singleton instance variable of a database handle.

Comment: you lost me at 'singleton instance variable of a database handle.' .. sounds good though... any website that I can read?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php

The docs are actually pretty good for this class, and should give you everything you need. You want the object approach, not the procedural one.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/). There is a little bit of ramp up but it is very nice.

Otherwise put that code in an include file and `include "db.php";` in your pages. Preferable you have 1 include file that gets you everything you need for your site, and you add the `$db` code there.

If you really want to be quick and dirty, make `$db` a global and then you can access it anywhere. This isn't great coding practice.